# Warning after updating php version 8.1

Tags: php, php-8.1

After updating PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1 , PHP produces following erro when cheking php version

`Deprecated: Return type of APCuIterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0`

I use :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Any idea

Comment: This isn't an error, it's merely a notice that a particular practice is deprecated and won't be allowed in a future version. In other words it's warning you that something will become an error in future. For now you _could_ choose to suppress the notice, or at least just log it to a file and ignore it. Or you could choose to investigate it and try to modernise your code.

Comment: If you need more specific help, you'll need to provide a [mre] of the issue in your question - i.e. enough code for us to be able to understand/reproduce the issue. Right now we don't know anything about these classes and functions the notice is talking about.

Comment: i just migrate an existing app from php 7.4 to php 8.1 and i build my docker

Comment: Yes, you already said that. And I've explained what's happened and what you can do about it.

Comment: You can suppress these deprecated notices in your php.ini file.